# php resuming capacity for idm

Tags: php

My code is this in php file for downloading any file but resume capability showing unknown plz can u suggest me the code for that functionality

its my php page to download a file, have to change code or what to do for changing resume capability in idm ?

```
       if(!isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
       header('location:../index.php');}
       $uname=$_SESSION['uname'];
       $uid= $_SESSION['user_id'];
     function output_file($file, $name, $mime_type='')
     {
/*
This function takes a path to a file to output ($file),  the filename that the browser will see ($name) and  the MIME type of the file ($mime_type, optional).
*/

//Check the file premission
//if(!is_readable($file)) die('File not found or inaccessible!');

$size = filesize($file);
$name = rawurldecode($name);

/* Figure out the MIME type | Check in array */
$known_mime_types=array(
    "pdf" => "application/pdf",
    "txt" => "text/plain",
    "html" => "text/html",
    "htm" => "text/html",
    "exe" => "application/octet-stream",
    "zip" => "application/zip",
    "doc" => "application/msword",
    "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel",
    "ppt" => "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint",
    "gif" => "image/gif",
    "png" => "image/png",
    "jpeg"=> "image/jpg",
    "jpg" =>  "image/jpg",
    "php" => "text/plain"
);

if($mime_type==''){
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,"."),1));
    if(array_key_exists($file_extension, $known_mime_types)){
        $mime_type=$known_mime_types[$file_extension];
    } else {
        $mime_type="application/force-download";
    };
};

//turn off output buffering to decrease cpu usage
@ob_end_clean(); 

// required for IE, otherwise Content-Disposition may be ignored
if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');

header('Content-Type: ' . $mime_type);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$name.'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Length: 2052595');
header('Content-Range: bytes 339843-2392437/2392438');

/* The three lines below basically make the 
    download non-cacheable */
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Pragma: private');
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

// multipart-download and download resuming support
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
    list($a, $range) = explode("=",$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'],2);
    list($range) = explode(",",$range,2);
    list($range, $range_end) = explode("-", $range);
    $range=intval($range);
    if(!$range_end) {
        $range_end=$size-1;
    } else {
        $range_end=intval($range_end);
 }

$new_length = $range_end-$range+1;
header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
header("Content-Length: $new_length");
header("Content-Range: bytes $range-$range_end/$size");
} else {
    $new_length=$size;
    header("Content-Length: ".$size);
}

/* Will output the file itself */
$chunksize = 3*(1024*1024); //you may want to change this
$bytes_send = 0;
if ($file = fopen($file, 'r'))
{
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
    fseek($file, $range);

while(!feof($file) && 
(!connection_aborted()) && 
    ($bytes_send<$new_length)
      )
{
$buffer = fread($file, $chunksize);
    print($buffer); //echo($buffer); // can also possible
    flush();
    $bytes_send += strlen($buffer);
}
fclose($file);
} else
//If no permissiion
die('Error - can not open file.');
//die
die();
}
//Set the time out
set_time_limit(0);
$temp = explode("\\", $_REQUEST['filename']);

//path to the file
$file_path=$_REQUEST['filename'];


//Call the download function with file path,file name and file type
output_file($file_path, ''.$temp[3].'', 'text/plain');


     ?>
```

Comment: Pleaee use proper formatting for your code. And maybe elaborate your actual problem a bit more.

Comment: ok my problem is this, that when i am trying to download any file using Internet download manager, the file will be download but it idm showing Resume capability (unknown) and pause button is deactivated.

Comment: Does your PHP support resuming? and does ot report that to your clients? Cant find anything about that on your code snippet other than that your try to determine the requested range.

Comment: i am using XAMPP server , in that how to check that it supports resume capability or not.

Comment: Your PHP has to do that. See answer. You have to send your own headers.

Comment: i posted php page used for downloading

Comment: Your headers look ok, did you check that they are actually send out? Try to open the page with a browser and check the headers.

Comment: http://localhost/file_storage/user/download.php?filename=E:\upload\dharani\26a06files%20before%20format%2025-3-2013.rar  ,after running in browser url after downloading is looks like this.

Comment: If all looks like it should be, you might want to try some other clients if they have same problems. If not, idm might expect something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the RFC on headers on how to report your capabilities to your clients:

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

**14.5 Accept-Ranges**

The Accept-Ranges response-header field allows the server to
indicate its acceptance of range requests for a resource:

```
      Accept-Ranges     = "Accept-Ranges" ":" acceptable-ranges
      acceptable-ranges = 1#range-unit | "none"
```

Origin servers that accept byte-range requests MAY send

```
      Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

but are not required to do so. Clients MAY generate byte-range
requests without having received this header for the resource
involved. Range units are defined in section 3.12.

Servers that do not accept any kind of range request for a
resource MAY send

```
      Accept-Ranges: none
```

to advise the client not to attempt a range request.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$uname=$_COOKIE["uname"];
//echo $uname;
$file=$_REQUEST['filename'];
$file_name="E:\\upload\\$uname\\$file";
$fid=$_REQUEST['fid'];


$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","Net@123");
$db=mysql_select_db("file_storage",$con);
$query1=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM upload WHERE file_id=$fid");
$row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1);

    if($row1)
    {
        $file_db=$row1['name'];

// If the requested file is exist
    if(file_exists($file_name)){
            // Get the file size
            $file_size=filesize($file_name);
            // Open the file
            $fh=fopen($file_name, "r");


// Download speed in KB/s
            $speed=1024;


//Initialize the range of bytes to be transferred
            $start=0;
            $end=$file_size-1;


//Check HTTP_RANGE variable
            if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) &&
                    preg_match('/^bytes=(\d+)-(\d*)/', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], $arr)){

                    // Starting byte
                    $start=$arr[1];
                    if($arr[2]){
                            // Ending byte
                            $end=$arr[2];
                    }
            }


//Check if starting and ending byte is valid
            if($start>$end || $start>=$file_size){
                    header("HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable");
                    header("Content-Length: 0");
            }
            else{
                    // For the first time download
                    if($start==0 && $end==$file_size){
                            // Send HTTP OK header
                            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
                    }
                    else{
                            // For resume download
                            // Send Partial Content header
                            header("HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content");
                            // Send Content-Range header
                   header("Content-Range: bytes ".$start."-".$end."/".$file_size);
                    }
                    // Bytes left
                    $left=$end-$start+1;


                    // Send the other headers
                    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
                    // Content length should be the bytes left
                    header("Content-Length: ".$left);
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_db);

                    // Read file from the given starting bytes
                    fseek($fh, $start);
                    // Loop while there are bytes left
                    while($left>0){
                            // Bytes to be transferred
                            // according to the defined speed
                            $bytes=$speed*1024;
                            // Read file per size
                            echo fread($fh, $bytes);
                            // Flush the content to client
                            flush();
                            // Substract bytes left with the tranferred bytes
                            $left-=$bytes;
                            // Delay for 1 second
                            sleep(1);
                    }
            }


    fclose($fh);
    }
    else{
            //If the requested file is not exist
            //Display error message
            echo "File not found!";
    }
    }
    exit();

?>
```

This code worked for , files are downloading with resume capability...

Comment: ^ Voted ☺ You helped me a lot. & learned further.. If you have the code, can you share the full code about normal chunked file transfer ? 